# Why doesn't Git pull in new changes to the cloned repository on my VPS?

Tags: git, gitlab

I bought vps, on which I made `git clone`. Everything got well from gitlab. However, on the computer I made some corrections in the project, and then I made commit and push through sourcetree. The changes are in the gitlab repository, but when I want to download changes to my vps, I enter the `git pull` command and get the `'Already up-to-date'` message even though changes have been made. I am asking for help on how to solve this.

Comment: There are a zillion possible points of failure here. Are you sure you see the commit at Gitlab? Are you sure your VPS has the correct origin config? Are you sure Sourcetree has the correct origin config?

Comment: Yes, I saw commit in Gitlab. Hmm.. how can i check if i had correct origin config ?

Comment: `git remote -v` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Comment: This is my output in vps :

Comment: origin  https://gitlab.com/patrykprzybylski92/my-app.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/patrykprzybylski92/my-app.git (push)

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, its correct.